# How to join two select queries in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I have two queries. One query pulls the information based on the orders that have been scheduled to them in a day by employee. The other query pulls the number of orders that have been completed and paid in a day, along with the total amount of the revenue from the orders.

I have scraped the forums to get the code together to get these queries, but I need to have both queries joined together. I want to use this information in report builder once I get it done. It's probably simple for someone, but it's confusing me as I'm far from any sort of expert with SQL.

I only need one day at the moment, but found this code and modified for now and hope that I can use it in the future when needing week and month data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Query 1

```
declare @dt DATE = '20160823'
set DATEFIRST 7;
set @dt = dateadd(week, datediff(week, '19050101', @dt), '19050101');

;with dt as
(
    select 
        Technician = (CASE emp_id
                         WHEN 'CW697' THEN 'Joe Biggs'
                         WHEN 'DZ663' THEN 'Mimi Cassidy'
                      END),
        dw = datepart(weekday, DATE)
    from 
        dbo.ordemps 
    where 
        date >= @dt and date <dateadd(day, 7, @dt)
),
x AS
(
    select 
        Technician, dw = coalesce(dw,8),
        c = convert(varchar(11), COUNT(*))
    from 
        dt 
    group by 
        grouping sets((Technician), (Technician,dw))
 )
select 
    Technician, 
    [Sun] = coalesce([1], '-'),
    [Mon] = coalesce([2], '-'),
    [Tue] = coalesce([3], '-'),
    [Wed] = coalesce([4], '-'),
    [Thu] = coalesce([5], '-'),
    [Fri] = coalesce([6], '-'),
    [Sat] = coalesce([7], '-'),
    TOTAL =[8]
from 
    x
PIVOT 
    (MAX(c) FOR dw IN([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8])) as pvt;
```

Query 2

```
select
    case
       when grouping(d.m)=15 then 'Year ' + cast(max(d.y) as varchar(10))
       when grouping(date)=15 then datename(m, max(DATE)) + ' ' + cast(max(d.y) as varchar(10))
       else cast(cast([date] as date) as varchar(255))
    end as DATE,
    TotalOrders = /*sum(Amount)*/convert(varchar(11), COUNT(*)),
    TotalSales = sum(Amount),
    Technician = (CASE recv_by
                     WHEN 'CW697' THEN 'Joe Biggs'
                     WHEN 'DZ663' THEN 'Mimi Cassidy'
                  END)
from 
    ordpay
cross apply 
    (select
         datepart(yy, [date]),
         datepart(m, [date])
    ) d(y, m) 
where 
    [DATE] >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 1, getdate()), 0)
    and [date] < dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0)
group by 
    recv_by, d.y, rollup (d.m, date)
order by 
    d.y desc, grouping(d.m), d.m, grouping(DATE), DATE
```

Comment: Welcome To StackOverflow (SO)!  As much as we enjoy helping each other, we are not a code writing service.   Put some effort into the problem and  try and figure it out.  When you have problems then ask for help.  Often these questions are closed due to no problem being asked and insufficient displayed effort on the question part.  We don't do this to be mean or cruel but because those writing/maintaining this code should show some effort and others get paid for this type of work!

Comment: Im sorry if I came across as if I was simply asking someone to write software for me.  I have been working on this for over a day trying to figure it out.  I have read numerous posts here and have yet to fully grasp whats needed.  So, I decided to post a question here as well after a day of banging my head.

Comment: it will be much easier if you provide some code to generate input data and tel us what is the expected result. simply add a create table and some insert statements so we can use it to generate sample data. BTW I think is can be a valid question and worth to work on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the easiest level you can use can join sub-queries. Your example is a little trickier because you are using CTEs which can't go in the subquery. To get you going in the right direction it should generally look like this:

```
with cte1 as (),
cte2 as ()
select *
from (
    select *
    from tables
    where criteria  -- subquery 1 (cannot contain order by)
) a
join (  -- could be a left join
    select *
    from tables
    where criteria  -- subquery 2 (cannot contain order by)
) b
on b.x = a.x  --join criteria
where --additional criteria
order by --final sort
```

where subquery 1 would be your query 1 from `select Technician` to the end
and subquery 2 would be everything from your query 2 except the `order by`.

For further information on joins see the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx) documentation

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  This is heading me in the right direction.  I still have to make a few adjustments to it but your tips have really helped me allot.

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't going to research much it doesn't seem here's a clunky and quick way, and keeps it simple for you, without having to explain a lot if we were to join the queries together more elegantly.

The first set of code has 2 common table expressions (CTE). So, select those results into a temp. Notice the --addition here

```
....
select 
    Technician, 
    [Sun] = coalesce([1], '-'),
    [Mon] = coalesce([2], '-'),
    [Tue] = coalesce([3], '-'),
    [Wed] = coalesce([4], '-'),
    [Thu] = coalesce([5], '-'),
    [Fri] = coalesce([6], '-'),
    [Sat] = coalesce([7], '-'),
    TOTAL =[8]
into #someTemp                      --Addition here
from 
....
```

Do the same for your second query...

```
...
into #someOtherTemp                 --Addition here
from 
    ordpay
...
```

Then join them togehter...

```
select t1.someColumns, t2.someOtherColumns
from #someTemp t1
inner join #someOtherTemp t2 on t1.column = t2.column
```